# "cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'line'"

Tags: python, opencv

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Inspiron\PycharmProjects\car\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    cv2.line(img,(coord[0][0],coord[0][1],coord[1][0],coord[1][1]),(0,0,255),2)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'line'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Expected sequence length 2, got 4
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Expected sequence length 2, got 4
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. In the future, you should wrap your code in a code block for better formatting.

Comment: `(coord[0][0],coord[0][1],coord[1][0],coord[1][1])` You're passing a tuple of four coordinates as the second argument.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The line function expects two coordinates (x0,y0) and (x1,y1). Try changing your call to this:

```
cv2.line(img,(coord[0][0],coord[0][1]),(coord[1][0],coord[1][1]),(0,0,255),2)
```

See the following [link](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_drawing_functions/py_drawing_functions.html) for an example.